# RSS feed aplication doesn't work right on different Android versions

Tags: java, android

I an trying to launch an application from [github](https://github.com/eddydn/AndroidRSSFeed) for rss news feed  and it is working fine on Android Oreo, but when I try to launch it on Marshmallow when I click to open a single news it crashes. 
Does someone know what is the reason for this problem?

That is the My error Log:

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@f7ad777 time:310406928
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.alex.navigationbottomnew, PID: 25664
                  android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:734)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:721)
                      at com.example.alex.navigationbottomnew.Adapter.FeedAdapter$1.onClick(FeedAdapter.java:87)
                      at com.example.alex.navigationbottomnew.Adapter.FeedViewHolder.onClick(FeedAdapter.java:45)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25664 SIG: 9
```

Comment: It is exactly opposite. The app is working great on Android 6+ and crashes on older versions.

Comment: post your crash log